# Android error: Path requests must specify a user by using UserEnvironment

Tags: android, file

When I am running the code in Android system service: I get the following error:

12-10 15:27:43.762: A/Environment(674): Path requests must specify a user by using UserEnvironment

The code that gives error is:

```
if (ext.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    loc = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); // this line gives error
}
```

Why does it show this error ?
Thanks.

Comment: have you added READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in manifest?

Comment: well, this code would be running inside android system service.

Comment: sorry, here what do you mean by android system service?]

Comment: For example, TELEPHONY_SERVICE. So I make changes to the system service code, add new functionality etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used:

```
Environment.setUserRequired(false);
```

to get rid of the error.

Answer (score 1):

This is a requirement/check from Android frameworks/base:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Environment.java See Lines: 811 - 820.

To solve this problem, add

> Environment.setUserRequired(false);

or

> Environment.setUserRequired(true);

whichever is appropriate to section of your code.

Ex. use of each: https://github.com/VanirAOSP/frameworks_base/commit/073bb2aa05163f97efe03dfc7d8f6e9be92cab5a