# Path requests must specify a user by using UserEnvironment

Tags: java, android

I am getting "Path requests must specify a user by using UserEnvironment" error by using

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

I traced my code and I found that in java.io.Environment there is a function to produce this error :

```
 private static void throwIfUserRequired() {
     if (sUserRequired) {
         Log.wtf(TAG, "Path requests must specify a user by using UserEnvironment",
                 new Throwable());
     }
 }
```

I searched in the web and found this solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488614/android-error-path-requests-must-specify-a-user-by-using-userenvironment)

```
Environment.setUserRequired(false);
```

But this solution is not working for me because I cannot access to the "setUserRequired" method of Environment. I get compilation error. I searched this function in the Environment class and I found this :

```
/** {@hide} */
public static void setUserRequired(boolean userRequired) {
    sUserRequired = userRequired;
}
```

Can anyone help me how can I access to my external storage of my phone? any solution ? it is emergency. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You need to use UserEnvironment and get the path for this user.

```
int userId = UserHandle.myUserId();
sCurrentUser = new UserEnvironment(userId);
```

This code stolen from Environment.java and the code they use to initialize their internal user.

Comment: `UserHandel` is in `android.os` but `myUsedrId` and `UserEnvironment` is not accessible. Could you run this these lines?

Comment: Its there, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/UserHandle.java

Comment: I saw it, like `Environment.setUserRequired(false)` it not accessible , what should I do now?

Comment: is there any setting inside the phone to define the user? this app is working for some phones but for mine which is nexus5 is not working? I am wondering how can be worked for some users and cannot work for others

Answer (score 0):

I could solve my problem by removing

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

inside try-catch block and writing outside of the try-catch block,and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Through the reflection to solve this problem

```
fun setUserRequired() {
    var state = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
    if ("mounted".equals(state)) {
        try {
            var environmentcls = Class.forName("android.os.Environment");
            var setUserRequiredM = environmentcls.getMethod("setUserRequired", Boolean::class.java);
            setUserRequiredM.invoke(null, false);
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
}
```